# Excel cannot open .xlsx file when file is saved via VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba, xlsx

I receive an error when trying to open a .xlsx file that wat saved using a VBA macro. I receive a message box saying "Excel cannot open the file 'filename.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid". But if I use "save as..." manually it opens correctly.
Also if I save the file via VBA macro but with .xls format it opens correctly as well.

This is the code I tried:

```
    Sub EMAIL()

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Dim Fecha As String
    Dim Ruta_archivo As String
    Dim Ruta As String
    Dim Nombre_archivo As String

    Fecha = Right$(Year(Date), 4) + Right$(100 + Month(Date), 2) + 
    Right$(100 + Day(Date), 2)
    Ruta = "path"
    Nombre_archivo = "filename"

    Ruta_archivo = Ruta + "\" + CStr(Year(Date)) + "\" + 
    MonthName(Month(Date), False) + "\" + Nombre_archivo + Fecha + ".xlsx"

    'Crear copia
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=Ruta_archivo
 
 

    End Sub
```

I expect the file to open correctly.

Comment: What is the fileformat of the workbook the code resides in?

Comment: The original file format is .xlsm

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook` may be not the workbook w/ code. If `ActiveWorkbook` is a xls file, use `SaveCopyAs`  to save it as a xlsx file. It raises the error when you try to open xlsx.

Comment: 'The original file format is .xlsm' - there's your answer. You have a .xlsm file, which you save a copy of with a .xlsx extension. That doesn't work. Either change you filename to end in .xlsm, or save as a .xlsx file by making a copy first: `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Copy: ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(Ruta_archivo,xlWorkbookDefault)`

Comment: Or rather, `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Copy: ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=Ruta_archivo, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save as xlsx file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37570620/how-to-save-as-xlsx-file)

Comment: @Paul answer seems to work. I just edited my code like this:

'Crear copia
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Copy: ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=Ruta_archivo, FileFormat:=51

 Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The original file format is .xlsm

That is the reason for your problem.

You have a .xlsm file, which you save a copy of with a .xlsx extension. That doesn't work. You can change the filename to end in .xlsm, or save it explicitly as a .xlsx file by making a copy first:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Copy ' Creates a new workbook with a copy of all sheets
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=Ruta_archivo, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault ' Saves it as .xlsx
```